# Are quantitative variables a subset of categorical variables?

Tags: self-study

Categorical variables consist of variables with exclusive sets of categories .Quantitative variables consist of variables with a numerical value but aren't numbers exclusive sets too ?

According to wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number

*A number is a mathematical object used to count, measure, and label.*

So a number is or can be seen as category too so will that make quantitative variables a set of categorical variables?

Answer (score 2):

Quantitative variables are usually ordinal and cardinal. So, number of children 3 and 6 means that one value is greater than the other, and moreover, it's twice more.

Categorical variables are usually not cardinal or even ordinal. For instance, a color RED is not greater or lesser than GREEN, it's just different.

> aren't numbers exclusive sets too?

Numbers are sets, but they're rather special. For instance, integer numbers are an infinite countable sets. However, in a computer they usually are represented with very large but still countable sets of INT or LONG type variables.

The real numbers are also sets, but they're not simply infinite, they're also uncountable. Again, in a computer they're usually represented with finite countable sets of floating point variables of type REAL, FLOAT, DOUBLE etc.

Numbers are always ordinal and cardinal.

The categorical variables are countable and usually finite sets. In fact, I never dealt with uncountable categorical sets in practice.

> So a number is or can be seen as category too so will that make quantitative variables a set of categorical variables?

Generally, no, but you can use numbers to denote categories. In this case though the variable is categorical, it's just its label is a number.